Asterisk in violin sheet music
I'm learning to play the violin using Suzuki's violin method, and in the piece “Gavotte”, there's an asterisk (*) symbol, and I don't know what it means. Does anyone know?



Is there a footnote at the bottom of the page?

You're referring to Gavotte by F.J. Gossec, the last piece of the Suzuki Violin method Volume 1.
As is usual in Suzuki Violin method books, the asterisk(s) function like footnotes in a book.  In those books, the "footnotes" are usually tips for learning a new technique.  For this piece, the "footnotes" are located in the next page in the form of a few bars of music notation below on how to practice step by step, with detailed fingering and bowing:



The first is to practice the acciaccatura grace notes (the asterisk in measure 4), and the second is to practice the fast sixteenth notes (double asterisks in measure 4 of the 2nd section), preceded by an explanatory text in 4 languages (English, German, French, and Spanish).  The English text:

Procedure for Practice.
Listen carefully to the intonation.  Use a short stroke.  Place the bow on the string, then play, keeping the bow on the string during the rest.


The memories. Except I learned it on viola.
